# Alternative for the word "please" or the right usage

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

Let's assume I'm texting or mailing a total stranger professionally or casually. If I would like to ask a query/question and need a definite response, I would write "Please do respond *some-text-here*". Consider the following examples/scenarios (communicated through a social media platform or email) :

1. Professional - I'm asking a vendor for the price quote and later add something along the lines of "Please do respond with a detailed quote or whether your firm is available/interested to proceed with the deal".
2. Casual - I'm asking a stranger for some information about a third person or even asking someone out on a date and say "Please reply/respond" or "Kindly reply/respond".

Now, all is fair in war and business they say. So, most people wouldn't mind a "Please" in "Scenario 1". But in the second case, when your self-respect is at stake, isn't "Please" a little too much? If I say that, since it is an indirect communication, it may even sound like you are desperate or begging. I mean, isn't there a better, non-creepy but polite/chivalrous way to ask the question? So that you sound like a gentleman?

Comment: [interpersonal.se] is probably the best place for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking someone to dinner, there really isn't any need to say the word ***please***. A simple "Would you like to come and have dinner with me on Thursday?" is perfectly courteous.

You only need ***please*** or an equivalent if you are asking a favour, such as "Do you possibly have any information about XX, if you do, please could you email it to me".

There are multiple other word formats one could use, such as **"would you be so kind as to..."**, **"would you be good enough to..."**, that you don't actually always have to say **"please"**.

Get a list and try rehearsing them.